# How do I return the value of the node before an item is present?

Tags: java, data-structures, methods, linked-list, nodes

I am working on a project for my Data Structures class that asks me to write a class to implement a linked list of ints.

> - Use an inner class for the Node.
> - Include the methods below.
> - Write a tester to enable you to test all of the methods with whatever data you want in any order.

I have to create a method called "private Node getPreviousNode". This method is meant to "return the value of the node that comes just before the item or null if it is not present." I have my code for this method down below. However, when I test this method I get the wrong output. It should return the value of the node that comes just before the item or null if it is not present. So for example if I had a list like so "9 10 2 5 16 18 17 1 2 19" and I wanted to get the previous node of 16 the method should return 5. But instead, it returns "LinkedListOfInts$Node@5b464ce8" Does someone know what I did wrong? and How to fix it?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedListOfIntsTest {
    Node head;

    private class Node {
        int value;
        Node nextNode;

        public Node(int value, Node nextNode) {
            this.value = value;
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        }

    }

    public LinkedListOfIntsTest(LinkedListOfIntsTest other) {
        Node tail = null;
        for (Node n = other.head; n != null; n = n.nextNode) {
            if (tail == null)
                this.head = tail = new Node(n.value, null);
            else {
                tail.nextNode = new Node(n.value, null);
                tail = tail.nextNode;
            }
        }
    }

    public LinkedListOfIntsTest(int[] other) {
        Node[] nodes = new Node[other.length];
        for (int index = 0; index < other.length; index++) {
            nodes[index] = new Node(other[index], null);
            if (index > 0) {
                nodes[index - 1].nextNode = nodes[index];
            }
        }

        head = nodes[0];
    }

    public LinkedListOfIntsTest(int N, int low, int high) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            this.addToFront(random.nextInt(high - low) + low);
    }

    public void addToFront(int x) {
        head = new Node(x, head);
    }

    private Node getPreviousNode(int item) {
        Node previous = null;
        for (Node ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.nextNode) {
            if (ptr.value == item)
                return previous;
            previous = ptr;
        }
        return null;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = " ";
        for (Node ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.nextNode)
            result += ptr.value + " ";
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        LinkedListOfIntsTest list = new LinkedListOfIntsTest(10, 1, 20);
        LinkedListOfIntsTest copy = new LinkedListOfIntsTest(list);
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("1. Get Previous Node");
            System.out.println("2. toString");
            switch (input.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Get Previous Node");
                System.out.println(list.getPreviousNode(input.nextInt()));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("toString");
                System.out.println(list.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? If it's the `value` of the `Node`, you'll need to implement `toString` on your `Node` class.

Comment: @tgdavies It should return the value of the node that comes just before the item or null if it is not present. So for example if I had a list like so "9 10 2 5 16 18 17 1 2 19" and I wanted to get the previous node of 16 the method should return 5. But instead, it returns "LinkedListOfInts$Node@5b464ce8".

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt this code was from what I worked on in class. But the professor wanted us to modify the code so it would return the value of the node that comes just before the item or null if it is not present. However, my understanding of Linked List is not that great since I only started learning about them a week ago and I have a project on this due on Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This method is meant to *"return the value of the node that comes just before the item or null if it is not present."* I have my code for this method down below

Since the method must return ***the value*** of the node, it shouldn't return the node instance itself, but its `value` member.

As your node values are `int`s, choosing that as the function's return type would seem appropriate, but as you must also foresee a `null` return value, the return type should be `Integer`.

Finally, there is another problem with the function: when calling `search` with a value that does not occur in the list at all, it returns the tail node of the list. Also in that case, it should return `null`.

Here is a possible correction:

```
private Integer getPreviousNode(int item) {
    if (head != null)
        for (Node previous = head; previous.nextNode != null; previous = previous.nextNode)
            if (previous.nextNode.value == item)
                return previous.value;
    return null;
}
```